# Database error in web api

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to create an odata endpoint for a table valued function in sql database. I get the exception:

The specified type member is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

I am sure with my code and unable to find the result, i am using ADO.NET entity framework.

Comment: Do you know where it is occurring? Does it show a line or anything? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common error and there is probably some bug in the ADO.NET EF .

In my case the error occurred when the edmx model generated had one of the entities listed  in upper case, which in the database is listed in lower case. Strange error to find. I modified my model accordingly.